# How to set_names after using pull on a list column in the tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Given the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
my_tibble <- tibble(
  var_1 = c("label_a", "label_b", "label_c"),
  var_2 = c("another_x", "another_y", "another_z"),
  result = list(
    data.frame(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3),
    data.frame(x = 4, y = 5, z = 6),
    data.frame(x = 5, y = 10, z = 11)
  )
)

my_tibble
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   var_1   var_2     result          
#   <chr>   <chr>     <list>          
# 1 label_a another_x <df[,3] [1 x 3]>
# 2 label_b another_y <df[,3] [1 x 3]>
# 3 label_c another_z <df[,3] [1 x 3]>
```

If we `pull` the result list-column, we get:

```
my_tibble %>% pull(result)

# [[1]]
#   x y z
# 1 1 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
#   x y z
# 1 4 5 6
# 
# [[3]]
#   x  y  z
# 1 5 10 11
```

How can I set the names (e.g. `set_names()`) of this pulled result by referring to more than one column from the original tibble? That is, instead of an unnamed list, I would like that list to have names referring to the tibble such as:

```
# $`label_a | another_x`
#   x y z
# 1 1 2 3
# 
# $`label_b | another_y`
#   x y z
# 1 4 5 6
# 
# $`label_c | another z`
#   x  y  z
# 1 5 10 11
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it in the other order instead?

```
> my_tibble %>%
    mutate(result = set_names(result,paste(var_1,var_2,sep = " | "))) %>%
    pull(result)

$`label_a | another_x`
  x y z
1 1 2 3

$`label_b | another_y`
  x y z
1 4 5 6

$`label_c | another_z`
  x  y  z
1 5 10 11
```

Comment: Love it (!) and embarrassingly obvious, but for some I reason I don't "think" and pipe that way. Curious if there are ways to do it post `pull`.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of `tibble` have the functions `enframe` and `deframe`, although as of v2.1.3 they both say they're maturing. `deframe` creates a named list out of a data frame. It assumes that the first column is the names and the second is the values, so just make a column (I used `tidyr::unite`) for the names.

```r
library(dplyr)

my_tibble %>%
  tidyr::unite(key, var_1, var_2, sep = " | ") %>%
  tibble::deframe()
#> $`label_a | another_x`
#>   x y z
#> 1 1 2 3
#> 
#> $`label_b | another_y`
#>   x y z
#> 1 4 5 6
#> 
#> $`label_c | another_z`
#>   x  y  z
#> 1 5 10 11
```

Comment: Interesting, while not clear in my example, I'd prefer something a little more flexible (i.e., not relying on the first / second column requirements), but hope to remember this for other things.

Comment: Got it. It is pretty inflexible, I imagine the tidy-devs will add a few arguments to it in the future since it's a pretty new addition. So in practice are you looking to have other columns included in the final data frames? Or you just want to avoid reducing down to two columns?